# Why am I not able to return a fragment?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-fragments

I'm getting an error on the line containing `return MyFragment.get(position);` inside the `MyViewPageAdapter` class.

Upon hovering over the error, the error is telling me:

`Incompatible types. 
Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found:android.app.Fragment`

How can I fix this?

Here's `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout MyTabs;
    ViewPager MyPage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MyTabs = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyTabs);
        MyPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.MyPage);

        MyTabs.setupWithViewPager(MyPage);
        setUpViewPager(MyPage);

    }

    public void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpage) {
        MyViewPageAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new Page_1(), "Page 1");
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new Page_2(), "Page 2");
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new Page_3(), "Page 3");

        viewpage.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    public class MyViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> MyFragment = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> MyPageTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyViewPageAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void AddFragmentPage(Fragment Frag, String Title) {
            MyFragment.add(Frag);
            MyPageTitle.add(Title);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MyFragment.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return MyPageTitle.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your `FragmentPagerAdapter` is incorrect.

`private List<Fragment> MyFragment = new ArrayList<>();`

The `Fragment` in your `List<Fragment>` is of type `android.app.Fragment`, it should be of type `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

just remove this import statement in your file, ot should be at the top:

`import android.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

You can return `android.app.Fragment`:

```
@Override
public android.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return MyFragment.get(position);
}
```

Or MyFragment must extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` :

```
class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {}
```

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting errors in Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new Page_1(), "Page 1"); . But it did remove the error I was referring to in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the very first line:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with this one:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

In the Android Sdk, there are two different `Fragment` classes. [One](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()) added in API 11 and [one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) added in API 22. The latter provides `Fragment` functionality for API level *below 11*.

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting errors in `Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new Page_1(), "Page 1");` .  But it did remove the error I was referring to in my original post.

Comment: I suspect that `Page_1`, `Page_2` and `Page_3` are `Fragment`s derived (`extends`) from the wrong class (`android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). The first line of the class declaration should read: `public class Page_1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the First line of import android.app.fragment. Add android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting errors in Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new Page_1(), "Page 1"); . But it did remove the error I was referring to in my original post.

Comment: where you are creating the frament instance ?  
refer this page <https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter>